# How to implement OAuth2 + PKCE in React Native app?

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, react-native, spring-security-oauth2, pkce

I'm having troubles to connect my app's frontend with the spring boot authService my dev made. He used oauth2 and PKCE. We can authenticate via insomnia or postman but I just can't connect it from the native js code. I'm trying to use expo-auth-session lib, because I'm using expo to run the app. How should I connect my native app with our server? (I dont want to use login with google!)

Comment: Hello, have you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: hi, not yet. I worked with glideapps to build a mvp for the months. Now we are coding the real thing again and in the next week I will try again to login the way I said. Can you help me?